# Rochel's tears vs. Leah's tears

Tags: imahot-matriarch-mothers

In the Torah, Leah cried because she didn't wish to marry Esav, and wished to marry Yaakov instead. However, post-death, Rochel cried about the fate of the nation when we entered our exile. 
Why would Leah, then, be considered the 'wife of Israel' and primary mother of our Nation? 
Shouldn't the title go to Rochel instead?

Comment: I think both of them are considered the "wife of Israel" and mother of our nation. I think Leah gets more of that though because most of the tribes are descended through her.

Comment: Who said Leah is considered the 'wife of Israel' and primary mother of our Nation?

Comment: Where does The Torah say that "Leah cried because she didn't wish to marry Esav"?

Comment: @Mike I think he means rashi.

Answer (score 2):

Eicha Rabbah (introduction 24), tells of Rachel pleading with God that for her sake and how she did not embarrass Leah, her children she be saved from exile. And God listened to her plea.

*It was indeed Rachel who was consulted, not Leah.*

It does not call her the wife of Israel, but it does imply that she is the mother interceding for her children. (רחל מבכה על בניה.)

> וגמלתי חסד עמה ולא קנאתי בה ולא הוצאתיה לחרפה ומה אני שאני בשר ודם עפר ואפר לא קנאתי לצרה שלי ולא הוצאתיה לבושה ולחרפה ואתה מלך חי וקיים רחמן מפני מה קנאת לעבודת כוכבים שאין בה ממש והגלית בני ונהרגו בחרב ועשו אויבים בם כרצונם מיד נתגלגלו רחמיו של הקדוש ברוך הוא ואמר בשבילך רחל אני מחזיר את ישראל למקומן הדא הוא דכתיב (ירמיה ל"א)כה אמר ה' קול ברמה נשמע נהי בכי תמרורים רחל מבכה על בניה מאנה להנחם על בניה כי איננו

Answer (score 1):

In the kinos It is clearly stated that **Three out of four OF THE *IMAHOS*** [matriarchs], (and also the  Avos, (forefathers), and Bilhah and Zilpah too) cried to Hashem on behalf of the Jews going into exile.

See kinah #26 at length. It ends:

> קול בכי לאה מתופפת על לבביה, רחל אחותה מבכה על בניה וזילפה מכה פניה
>   בילהה מקוננת בשתי ידיה

And Hasem responds to all of them:

> שובו תמימים למנוחתכם מלא אמלא כל משאלותיכם שלחתי בבלה למענכם הנני משבב
>   גלות בניכם

See kinah #39 which also lists Sarah, Rachel, Leah, Bilhah, and Zilpah, as crying, but it does not say who was responded to.

related: [Didn't Rivkah also cry when the Jews were exiled?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94155/didnt-rivkah-also-cry-when-the-jews-were-exiled)