# Didn't Rivkah also cry when the Jews were exiled?

Tags: song-poetry, tisha-bav, imahot-matriarch-mothers, golus-exile

In the kinos of Tishah B'Av it is clearly stated that **Three out of four** of the *Imahos* [matriarchs], (and also the Avos, forefathers, and Bilhah and Zilpah too) cried to Hashem on behalf of the Jews going into exile.

See kinah #26 at length. It ends:

> קול בכי לאה מתופפת על לבביה, רחל אחותה מבכה על בניה וזילפה מכה פניה
>   בילהה מקוננת בשתי ידיה

And Hasem responds to all of them:

> שובו תמימים למנוחתכם מלא אמלא כל משאלותיכם שלחתי בבלה למענכם הנני משבב
>   גלות בניכם

See kinah #39 which also lists **Sarah**, Rachel, Leah, Bilhah, and Zilpah, as crying.

I wonder why Rivkah is not listed among the others. Did she not cry??

Related: [Rochel's tears vs. Leah's tears](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94137/rochels-tears-vs-leahs-tears/94154#94154)

Comment: I don't have a Kinnos open in front of me now, but based on your quotes, Kinah #26 wouldn't be a question on its' own. That can be easily explained as only quoting the last set of Imahos (who were the mothers of the Shevatim). If Kinah #39 internally mentions all the Imahos minus Rivkah, I think that would be a stronger question.

Comment: @Salmononius2 "Kinah #26 wouldn't be a question on its' own". - That's  why i didn't ask it on its own.

Comment: The [famous Midrash](https://www.sefaria.org/Eichah_Rabbah,_Petichta.24) about Rochel crying only mentions the Avos and Moshe crying. None of the other imahos are mentioned. However, the Aruch HaShulchan [assumes](https://parshaponders.com/pesach-tzav-5777/#_ftnref10) all of them were crying as well.